# ¿Cómo convierto de decimal a binario en C++?

Tags: c++, algoritmos

Recien comienzo en programación y me dejaron de tarea este programa, pero no tengo idea de cómo resolverlo. Había escuchado hablar del método de la burbuja, pero no sé cómo implementarlo en el algoritmo, ¿Alguien podria orientarme?

Comment: [¿Sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): *Preguntas solicitando ayuda con trabajo escolar deben incluir un resumen del trabajo que has realizado hasta el momento para resolver el problema y una descripción de la dificultad que estás teniendo para resolverlo.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Espero que esto te ayude:

```
 #include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int x;
    cout << "Ingrese numeros, 0 para terminar:" << endl;
    cin >> x;
    while (x != 0){
        vector<int> v;
        while(x > 0){
            v.push_back(x % 2); // Almaceno los restos en una pila
            x = x / 2;          // Reduzco x
        }
        for (int i = (v.size() - 1); i >= 0; i--) // Imprimo los numeros de atras para delante
            cout << v[i];
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Ingrese numeros, 0 para terminar:" << endl;
        cin >> x;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, ahora investigare para que sirve cada funcion en el codigo ya que hay algunas que desconozco.

Comment: De nada! Sisi, te recomiendo mucho ver todas las funciones así no solo es copiar código y aprendes mucho. Saludos!

Answer (score 2):

Aunque ya esté respondida esta respuesta, aporto mi granito de arena:

**opción 1: simplificación de la otra solución propuesta**

```
int main(){
  int x;

  cout << "Ingrese numeros, 0 para terminar:" << endl;
  cin >> x;
  while (x)
  {
    vector<char> v;
    v.reserve(8*sizeof(int));

    do
    {
      v.push_back(x&1 + '0'); // Almaceno los restos en una pila
    } while( x >>= 1); // Reduzco x

    std::string enBinario(v.rbegin(),v.rend());
    std::cout << enBinario << '\n';
    cout << "Ingrese numeros, 0 para terminar:" << endl;
    cin >> x;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

**opción 2: usando bitset**

```
int main()
{
  int numero;
  std::cout << "Introduce un número: ";
  std::cin >> numero;
  std::cout << "Representación en binario: ";
  std::bitset<32> enBinario(numero);
  std::cout << enBinario<< '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres solo imprimirlo, te recomiendo que utilices el siguiente algoritmo recursivo que no solo te convierte de decimal a binario, sino a cualquier base. Si la base es mayor que 10 tendrias que hacer un par de retoques pero es minimo. Ahi te va:

```
void convert(int n, int base) {
    if(n < 0) return;
    if(n < base)
        printf("%d", n);
    else {
        convert(n / base, base);
        printf("%d", n % base);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

esta es la forma en que yo lo hago

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n,bin=0,cont=1;
    cin>>n;
    while(n>0){
        bin=bin+(n%2)*cont;
        cont=cont*10;
        n=n/2;
    }
    cout<<bin<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```